# Twilio Android Application Error - AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST

Tags: android, twilio

I've been working with the android app guide at:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client

On phones with US-Cellular, I am getting the following errors with the core library's:

```
01-02 12:48:41.102: W/LEMUR(21969): Dial Button Push
01-02 12:48:41.122: W/AudioTrack(21969): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
01-02 12:48:41.122: E/AudioTrack(21969): AudioTrack::set : Exit
01-02 12:48:41.122: W/AudioRecord(21969): AUDIO_INPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
```

Any suggestions how to work around this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Always [enable the debug log](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/twilio#public-static-void-setloglevelint-level) and attach the relevant output with the issue.

```
Twilio.setLogLevel(int level);
```

The level parameter values correspond to the levels provided by the Android SDK : `Log.ASSERT Log.DEBUG Log.ERROR Log.INFO Log.VERBOSE Log.WARN.`

This is likely expected behavior if there is contention for audio resources. These kinds of log messages seem to appear when Twilio Client runs concurrently with other audio apps or VoIP apps.

One way to handle this would be to catch any runtime exceptions to try to display a suitable user-facing error message.